# PyCharm - Add Sources Root to GitHub

Tags: python, pycharm, project

I have an old project (`OldProject`) stored at some location on my Desktop, I've started a new project (`NewProject`) which uses files from `OldProject`.

The two projects are in two completely different directories and `OldProject` can exist entirely on its own without `NewProject` (meaning I can't refactor it into `NewProject` as it'll move the directory, which I do **not** want)

Now to use the scripts from `OldProject` in `NewProject`:

1. Opened `NewProject` in PyCharm
2. Opened `OldProject` and then clicked Attach to attach it to `NewProject`
3. Went into project settings and marked `OldProject` as a sources root and made it a dependency of `NewProject`
4. In the same menu, I added it as a content root so that it is now in my Project View

I then carried on with development.

Now, I would like to share `NewProject` on GitHub but (to my surprise) the initial commit did not include any files from `OldProject` meaning it's quite useless to anyone else.

Is there a way I can explicitly add `OldProject` to `NewProject` **without** having to copy over all the files and updating the import statements (in both projects) as such?

When using the scripts from `OldProject` in `NewProject` the import statements are something like:

```
import old_project_folder
```

As opposed to:

```
import OldProject.old_project_folder
```

i.e. within the IDE, `OldProject` and `NewProject` are *shown* to be in the same location.

However, I can't run the program in `NewProject` anywhere else than PyCharm because the import statements aren't correct.

I have also tried programmatically inserting the directory into driver script:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.path.insert(1, path_to_old_project)
    run()
```

But that hasn't worked.

I have tried to add an `__init__.py` to `OldProject` to make it a module but I have several directories and subdirectories so I'd like to know if there's a way to achieve the same outcome before going further with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (to my surprise) the initial commit did not include any files from OldProject meaning it's quite useless to anyone else.

That is because `OldProject` is not in your git repository. You can find the improper solution to what you want [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/8631184).

The proper solution to this is to make `OldProject` a stand-alone package, make it a dependency of `NewProject`, and install it via pip or setuptools.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I think I'll prefer to make it a package instead, is there some documentation you could point me to?

Comment: Here is the official Python tutorial on the topic. https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/